# Работа с файлом Word в с# Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"

Tags: c#

```
public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        public static string generalfile = Application.StartupPath + "\\Shablon\\1.docx"; // файл-шаблон
        public static string newfile = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + Program.namePath + "\\протокол1.docx"; // новый файл на основе файла-шаблона
        public static Object fileName = generalfile;
        public static Object missing = Type.Missing;
        public void OpenFile()
        {
            app.Documents.Open(ref fileName);
        }
        public void SaveCloseFile()
        {
            app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(newfile);
            app.ActiveDocument.Close();
            app.Quit();
        }
        public void FindReplace(string str_old, string str_new)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find find = app.Selection.Find;

            find.Text = str_old; // текст поиска
            find.Replacement.Text = str_new; // текст замены

            find.Execute(FindText: Type.Missing, MatchCase: false, MatchWholeWord: false, MatchWildcards: false,
                        MatchSoundsLike: missing, MatchAllWordForms: false, Forward: true, Wrap: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue,
                        Format: false, ReplaceWith: missing, Replace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

        }
```

При повторном создание файла ругается на метод `openFile` исключением `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

Сам вызов:

```
OpenFile();
FindReplace("name", Program.namePath);
FindReplace("Predsedatel", predsedatel_name + " - " + dolzhnostPred);
FindReplace("V1", textBox6.Text.Trim());
FindReplace("V2", textBox7.Text.Trim());
FindReplace("V3", textBox8.Text.Trim());
FindReplace("Com1", comissionname[0] + " - " + dolzhnostCom[0]);
FindReplace("Com2", comissionname[1] + " - " + dolzhnostCom[1]);
FindReplace("Com3", comissionname[2] + " - " + dolzhnostCom[2]);
FindReplace("Com4", comissionname[3] + " - " + dolzhnostCom[3]);
FindReplace("Secretar", secretar_name + " - " + dolzhnostSec);
FindReplace("ocenkaGos", Program.ocenkaGos + " %");
SaveCloseFile();
```

Comment: Что значит «ругается»? Выбрасывается исключение? Тогда давайте текст исключения в вопрос, и `InnerException`, если есть.

Comment: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"

Comment: Хорошо, но мало. Ищите информацию в объекте исключения. Message? InnerException? HResult?

Comment: @VladD, чего телепатию выключил?))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно, хрустальный шар на подзарядке :-D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
> ```

Жил был Word...

> ```
> app.Quit();
> ```

... но его закрыли ...

> ```
> app.Documents.Open(ref fileName);
> ```

а потом попросили открыть файл...
но было уже некому...

---

В общем, перенеси

```
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

туда, где начинается работа - это где-то раньше вызова `OpenFile`.

Comment: не получается. он мне один и тот же файл изменяет . А у меня создается папка и туда подгружаем файл с изменениями

Comment: Смысл программы такой что бы из папкм с шаблоном она брала файл и записывала в созданную новую папку и туда уже записывала измененный файл.

Comment: А после того как поднял выше эту строчку  , все меняется в первой созданной папке

Comment: все работает , только пришлось поле с новыми путями убирать static . спасибо большое всем за участие\